# Postgres How can I get huge data

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, xml-rpc

I have program `java` client and `xmlrpc` server and `postgres` DB, I am retrieving data from 2 DB,
I have send 2 query to server and server return data to client inside `hashMap`.

but data is big, sometime its have more than 40000 rows, and if i am try to get it i get error from server say : `java` heap space

I am trying to set `-Xmx1024m and -Xmx512m ...` without any benefits

Now , what is the best way to fix it ?

I am getting data by this code :

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    String conString = "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + DBName + 
            "?user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;
    String conString1 = "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port2 + "/" + DBName2 + 
            "?user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;  
      c = DriverManager.getConnection(conString);
      c2 = DriverManager.getConnection(conString1);

      st = c.createStatement();
      st2 = c2.createStatement();

          List<ResultSet> resultSets = new ArrayList<>();
          resultSets.add(st.executeQuery(query));
          resultSets.add(st2.executeQuery(query2));
      //ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
           ResultSets rs = new ResultSets(resultSets);
      while (rs.next()){
          unbArrL.add(rs.getUnbalance("unbalance"));
      }
```

and **ResultSets class** to get values is :

```
class ResultSets {

 private java.util.List<java.sql.ResultSet> resultSets;

    private java.sql.ResultSet current;


    public ResultSets(java.util.List<java.sql.ResultSet> resultSets) {
        this.resultSets = new java.util.ArrayList<>(resultSets);
        current = resultSets.remove(0);
    }

    public boolean next() throws SQLException {
        if (current.next()) {
            return true;
        }else if (!resultSets.isEmpty()) {
            current = resultSets.remove(0);
            return next();
        }
        return false;
    }   
    public Double getUnbalance(String unbalance) throws SQLException{
        return current.getDouble("unbalance");
    }
}
```

Can you give me clear solutions and some code or examples?

Comment: use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

Comment: Use a cursor based result set, otherwise everything will be loaded into memory. Details are in the documentation: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: Is it really necessary to keep all that data in the ram? what for? Showing 40.000 rows to an user seems not to be a good idea.
You could set setMaxRows on your Statement instance. Or use an appropriate where filter in your sql. Or you can buffer the data on disc.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious way to get around this issue would be to split your result in different pages and use `LIMIT`s and (`OFFSET`s).

If you really need to output the whole dataset at once, you should *not* populate a collection with the results, but instead return an `Iterable` (or a mere `Iterator`, as you'll only be able to iterate the result sets once) that will fetch the rows in the DB one by one, as they are requested by the component which emits the (formatted) response.

Therefore, you'll need to replace all the `List`s returned by you query methods with `Iterator`s and make the `hasNex()` and `next()` methods of the `Iterator` invoke the corresponding logic in the underlying DB `ResultSet`.

You could also return the original SQL `ResultSet` all the way up to your controller, but this would be a poor separation of concerns.

The end result of this approach would be that the rows will be fetched one at a time and sent to the client output stream, so you'll have a constant memory footprint, no matter how huge your queries are.